# How to determine columns that will be returned in the result when using `paginate()` method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have 2 tables: `users` and `articles`. To fetch all columns from the `articles` table and only `user_name` column from the `users` table, I use this code:

```
$articles = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
    ->get(array('articles.*', 'users.user_name'));
```

and it works fine, but when I use `paginate()` method like this:

```
$articles = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', 'users.user_id')
    ->paginate(10);
```

it fetches all columns from both tables, which I don't want. My question is: How can I select columns that will be returned in the result if I use `paginate()` method in Laravel framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [select](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins) function does this.

```
$articles = Article::join('users', 'articles.user_id', '=', users.user_id')
    ->select('articles.*', 'users.user_name')
    ->paginate(10);
```